# How is it (that) Subject Verb ~~~

Tags: connotations

[Do "How is it that...?" and "How...?" mean the same thing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55679/do-how-is-it-that-and-how-mean-the-same-thing)

Hi

I've looked at the above post. Now I want to know the nuance of "how is it (that) S V~~?".

Tᴚoɯɐuo said,

> This form of question, How is it that ...? implies that the speaker is
> finding something hard to believe or difficult to comprehend:
>
> ***How is it that the ship ran aground if its navigational systems were***
> ***functioning properly?***
>
> ***If you are not the art thief, how is it that the missing paintings***
> ***ended up in the trunk of your car?***
>
> The facts would suggest otherwise. The How-is-it form of question is
> asked in light of something already known, something which has already
> happened.
>
> ***How is it that we are able to remain enthusiastic after all of these***
> ***setbacks?***

So now, I want to figure out his feedback about "*The facts would suggest otherwise. The How-is-it form of question is asked in light of something already known, something which has already happened*".
The facts that the Tᴚoɯɐuo said refer to "If clause ~", do they???

And then
When the facts are really actual and have taken place, in this case, the intention of "How is it that S V" is to ask for the specific reason with surprise, disbelief, or disapproval?

For example)

```
How is it that you are always behind time?

How is it that you missed the appointment?
```

Comment: For both of your examples, it would be more common to say "Why" than "How"

Comment: _How is it that...?_ has the sense _How did it happen that...?_  If the ship's navigational systems were working, how did it run aground? If the driver didn't steal the paintings, how did they get into his car? So, yes, the questions are asked with surprise or disbelief.